# How to take a screenshot of the lock screen in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, screenshot, lock-screen

How can I take a screenshot of the lock screen in Windows 8?

Note that Windows 8 shows a lock screen with a wallpaper and in the bottom-left corner shows the date-time with notification icons of wireless and battery. This is the lock screen I wish to capture.

But, if you press any key on this lock screen, it goes away and Windows 8 displays your profile picture and a password field asking you to enter it to unlock Windows. This is NOT the lock screen I wish to capture.

Comment: What key combinations have you tried?

Comment: Try "Win buttom" + "PrintScreen".

Comment: Possible Dupe: [How can I take a screenshot of my logon screen in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/158976/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-of-my-logon-screen-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: Techie007: That question is about the login screen of Windows 7 not 8.

Comment: Diogo: Win + PrintScreen does not work.

Comment: Ramhound: PrintScreen and Win + PrintScreen both do not work.

Comment: @techie007 I actually agree that this is a different situation in this case and not a dupe IMO.  The Win 7 lock screen was static while the Win 8 Lock Screen isn't.

Comment: It's less ambiguous (and a better question) now that the OP had edited to add more information. :) It'd be nice to know if any of the methods mentioned in the other one were tried already.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the Windows 8 Login Screen Capture tool there : http://www.technoarea.in/how-to-take-screenshot-of-windows-8-login-screen/

The website says that it makes possible take a screenshot of the lock screen, by pressing the Windows Key + L.

Comment: Axel Isouard: Does not seem to work. After installing it, I do not see any new menu entry in the Ease of Access menu on the lock screen.

Comment: Did you restart your system ?

Comment: Th link is broken

Comment: @Minato Namikaze Working fine for me !

Comment: @AxelIsouard The link itself isn't broken. The Download link on that page is broken

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I know is to RDP in (further to Bali C answer) then you can use Print Screen.

Comment: Or use a VM. From the host you should be able to Alt-PrtSc the VM.